# How to increase width of editor in django-tinymce HTMLField?

Tags: python, django, tinymce

**models.py:**

```
..
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class MyModel(models.Model):
   ..
   description = HTMLField()
   ..
```

**admin.py**

```
..
from .models import MyModel
..


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

      fieldsets = (
          (None, {
              'fields': (.., 'description', ..,)
          }),
          ..
      ..
```

How to increase the width of the TinyMCE HTML Editor that appears in the default django admin model add template?
. Please note that I'm using HTMLField() in model and I don't want to create a Form using forms.py

Please let me know if you need anymore details.

Thanks in advance,

Pavan

Answer (score 0):

`HTMLField` is using `TinyMCE` widget, so you can just customize its number of cols this way:

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

class MyModel(models.Model):
   ...
   description = HTMLField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
   ...
```

Comment: Thought it works only in forms.py
Tried. Didn't work. It says -
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'